# Android seekbar goes out of its track towards the end

Tags: android, seekbar

I am having an issue with a kind of custom seekbar What I have done is created a new object that extends SeekBar.
Then in onSizeChanged function, I am calculating the width, and setting it up, and the pass that size on to super.onSizeChanged() function.
Now this gives me perfectly correct width of the SeekBar track, however, when I push and drag the SeekBar thumb, more it moves towards right, thumb moves further a head of the seekbar track filling color area. So much so that it moves to the edge of the available screen where as the color filled width of the track is behind.

I hope some kind soul can guide..There is nothing fancy its simple manual intervention to change the width in onSizeChanged and thats it.
Here is the XML that I am using for this

```
<com.test.SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dip"
    android:progress="0"
    android:max="100"
    android:progressDrawable="@layout/progressbar"
    android:secondaryProgress="0" 

    />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution to my problem. My solution is a mix of xml and setting up layout parameters programmatically in the main activity.

1. I enclosed the seekbar xml element in another linear layout element(now I had only one control in this linear layout element
2. Then in code I just calculated the desired width as I wanted and set the layout params
   as below

   ```
   int newWidth  = getSeekBarWidthAsNeeded();
   int newHeight = getDesiredHeight();// smaller for lareger screens

   LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(newWidth,newHeight);
   mySeekBar.setLayoutParams(llp);
   ```

And this finally took care of my struggle with working with onSizeChanged and other methods, which I had soo much trouble with